# Removing first line from string in Groovy

Tags: xml, string, groovy

With Groovy I need to read an XML file and remove the first line containing the XML declaration.

**Source content**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<myxmldoc>
  content
</myxmldoc>
```

**Target content**

```
<myxmldoc>
  content
</myxmldoc>
```

**My code so far...**
Reading all lines except the first line from the file into a list. Then, building a new string by adding each line to the next.

```
def soapBodyList = new File(inputFilename).readLines()
soapBodyList = soapBodyList[1..soapBodyList.size-1]

def soapBody = ""
soapBodyList.each {
    soapBody += it
}

return soapBody
```

However I feel that there must be a simpler way to just remove the first line abnd have the result as a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
def soapBodyList = new File(inputFilename).readLines()
return soapBodyList[1..soapBodyList.size-1].join("")
```

should do the trick

Comment: or instead of the range with `tail`: `soapBodyList.tail().join('')`